# Deadbeef - jump back/forward

Tags: linux, audio, keyboard-shortcuts, deadbeef

How to jump back and forward a few seconds in Deadbeef?

Can it be done by keyboard? Left/right arrows do nothing by themselves or with Ctrl or other key.

I have the impression that this option must exist but I don't seem to find it.

(I don't think db version 0.7.2 is affected by [this](https://github.com/alexey-yakovenko/deadbeef/issues/1190) old issue but the idea is similar.)

Comment: please leave a word with your down votes and help me die smarter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't touch those settings for a while - they are a bit hidden.

Go to *Preference* - *Hotkeys*

Click 'Add', then the button for 'Action'.

[image]

Go under **Main**, then **Playback** to select the action.

[image]

Then select 'Key combination' and click *Apply*.

These and other settings are saved in `~/.config/deadbeef/config` along other configuration files.

[image]

Backup `~/.config/deadbeef/` to keep such settings for a future installation.